# A complex exponent equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $0 \leq x < 1$, $0 < Re(\rho) < 1$.

> Then does this equation contain no solutions for x other than $x = \frac{1}{2}$?
>   $$2^\rho + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^\rho} + x$$

I am unable to find any answer.

EDIT: I have solved it. The answer is $x = \frac{1}{2}$ is the only solution for $0 \leq x < 1$. Basically I separated the real and imaginary parts and checked for conditions $0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2} < x < 1$, and used the inequality to produce contradictions in both cases. I think I will leave the details as an exercise.

Comment: Where does it come from and what have you tried?

Comment: Roupam, I think you should post your edit as an answer and validate it so that this question is considered resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Raskolnikov's suggestion I am adding my edit as an answer.

The answer is $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is the only solution for 0≤x<1. Basically I separated the real and imaginary parts and checked for conditions $0≤x<\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}<x<1$, and used the inequality to produce contradictions in both cases. I think I will leave the details as an exercise.